# How to set a different path for composer installer based on components inside a framework

Tags: php, path, installation, composer-php

I've been working on a PHP Framework development and we'd like to separate the components into individual packages from the core. Like this:

```
vendor /
    username/frameworkname /
        core/
            Namespace /
                Core /
                    ..Framework core files here
        components/
            Namespace /
                Component
                    ComponentOne
                        ClassOne.php
                        ClassTwo.php
                        composer.json
                        LICENSE.txt
                        README.md

                    ComponentTwo
                        ClassOne.php
                        ClassTwo.php
                        ClassThree.php
                        composer.json
                        README.md
                        LICENSE.txt

                    ComponentHopeYouFotIT!
```

Core being required by composer like this:

```
composer require name/framework-core
```

And be able to install it in

```
vendor/username/frameworkname/src/core/Namespace/Core/
```

And any component like this:

```
composer require name/componentname
```

And be able to install it in:

```
vendor/username/frameworkname/src/components/Namespace/Component/
```

So that we don't have to create a separate folder for any new component and could use like this:

```
use Namespace\Core\CoreClass;
use Namespace\Component\{
    ComponentOne\ClassTwo, 
    ComponentTwo\ClassOne
};
```

It that possible?

I've personally have tried Composer **composer/installers** but couldn't figure out the correct settings in composer.json to do the trick.

```
"config": {
    "vendor-dir": "vendor/username"
},
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "package",
        "package": {
        "name": "frameworkname/componentname",
            "version": "master",
            "source": {
                "url": "https://github.com/username/componentname",
                "type": "git",
                "reference": "master"
            }
        },
        "require": {
            "composer/installers": "~1.0"
        }
    }
],
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the [Composer Custom Installer documentation](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/custom-installers.md)? It does this.

The tl;dr is that you need to create a (very simple) Composer plugin to set custom install locations, and the documentation walks you through it very specifically.

**Aside:** My sense, having experimented a bit with `composer/installers`, is that it may not support custom types, but might allow you to set custom paths for supported types. That is: if you wanted to use a WordPress plugin, but install it somewhere different than normal, you could override the `install-paths`, but you couldn't necessarily use `composer/installers` to define your own type `whooptido-type` with a custom install location. This inference is based, I strenuously underscore, on empirical experience experimenting with it this morning, rather than actual documentation. ;)